# SPFx Extension - Page Context is missing

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-extensions

Recently I noticed, SPFx Extension is updated from drop build to RC (release candidate) build, because of that one of my `SPFx Extension Application Customizer` stopped working. I went to SPFx Extension documents and most of the things are updated in document and following them I was able to make my application customizer working.

But earlier, there was page context (`this.context.pageContext` object) variable available which is now removed from RC. I was using page context to get Web absolute url to do some REST API data pull and using `site logo` property to get the logo.

Is there any alternative available to get the page context in RC or it is completely removed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No its not removed or deprecated. Its working correctly . Just upgraded a sample and was able to work with the `this.context` object without any issue.

You need to ensure that you are using it inside the `onInit()` method because this event occurs after `this.context` is populated.

If you are using it before the `onInit` method, it will be undefined.

I have used the below sample code and it correctly logs the value in console (see following screenshot):

```
export default class TestappApplicationCustomizer
  extends BaseApplicationCustomizer<ITestappApplicationCustomizerProperties> {

  @override
  public onInit(): Promise<void> {

    console.log(this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl);

    return Promise.resolve<void>();
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes you are right. Thanks. Although yesterday I checked the complete `ApplicationCustomizerContext` and `ExtensionContext` to see if it there or not. But was not able to find it. Now I realized its in `BaseComponentContext` not in two mentioned above.